# Refactor aspx page using Eval and If Statement C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, refactoring

I was wonder if there is a better way of writing this code.

```
<%#Eval("hasAccess").Equals(true) ? "<a href='/CaseActivities.aspx?" + Eval("caseURL") + "'>" + Eval("caseName") + "</a>" : Eval("caseName")%>
```

I tried <% If (Eval("hasAccess") ... but asp.net doesnt like that :)

I was hoping for something like

```
<% If Eval("hasAccess") %>
do stuff .. 
<% else %>
do other stuff.
```

But when using the Eval with IF it get messy .. any thoughts?

Comment: _"I was wonder if there is a better way of writing this code"_ Yes, using codebehind.

Comment: this is stuff that ASP.NET MVC does easily, just FYI

Comment: @dferraro This is stuff that ASP.NET does easily if you don't try to do it in markup, as Tim suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should almost certainly be doing this in code behind, not in scriptlets.  In the case of data binding there are a few options:

1. Rather than performing these operations as a part of the data binding, change the underlying data source before binding it so that the data binding itself only takes the value as is.
2. Add a method to the code behind that takes the column and returns the proper value, that way the data binding method just needs to eval a call to that method passing this column.
3. Don't do the data binding in markup if it is going to be complex; use data binding events in code behind (when available).

Those are listed in the order of preference in which you should try to use them.

Comment: Re-wrote it in code-behind .. was lazy before. Thanks for the kick in the butt.